# How to add data attributes in Sitecore MVC fileds

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, sitecore8

My code:

```
<a data-toggle="dropdown">Associate Sites<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
```

I tried following code:

namespaces:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Glass.Mapper.Sc
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<CassiaMvc.Models.Footer>
```

Code:

```
  @Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Link Field", new { @data-toggle="dropdown" })
  @Html.Sitecore().Field("Destination URL", item)
  @Html.Sitecore().EndField()
```

But I getting error,
[image]

Please let me know what am doing wrong.

Comment: I tried with    @Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Link Field") 
                                  @Html.Sitecore().Field("Destination URL", item,, new {@data-toggle="dropdown" })
                                  @Html.Sitecore().EndField(), also getting same error.

Comment: I see you are importing Glass Mapper namespaces.  Is there a reason you are not using it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use hyphens for property names in a dynamic object. Change the hyphens to underscores:

```
 @Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Link Field", new { @data-toggle="dropdown" })
```

to

```
@Html.Sitecore().BeginField("Link Field", new { @data_toggle="dropdown" })
```

The field renderer should convert the underscores to hyphens when rendered.

Comment: Thanks, error gone, but not rendered  the attribute. <a href="http://" target="_blank" item="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item" isactive="False">Associate Sites</a>

Comment: This works in my dev. @Html.Sitecore().Field("Destination URL", item, new { @data_toggle="dropdown" })

Comment: Thanks dnstommy, working fine, could you please help me integrate of <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>  with in link field

Comment: I write code like this    @Html.Sitecore().Field("Destination URL", item.Item, new { @data_toggle = "dropdown" }) <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>, but getting like <a href="/en" data_toggle="dropdown">Associate Sites</a> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> , I would expect like <a data-toggle="dropdown">Associate Sites<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>

Comment: Hello Richard  "The field renderer should convert the underscores to hyphens when rendered." this saves my day. Thank you.